# Why there is a deadlock for given many readers and writers

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I'm practicing [readers and writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) and come up with the following solution. However, the program blocks itself after printing out the following results.

```
$ Read content: planets
```

My idea is a modified version of the [first solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem#First_readers-writers_problem). With 2 semaphores, one called *readMutex* ensuring only one read thread to update *numOfReaders* at a time, while the other semaphore called *accessToResource* ensuring that when readers are reading content, the writer should wait. Here's my code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ReadersAndWriters {
    public static final Semaphore accessToResource = new Semaphore(1, true);
    public static final Semaphore readMutex = new Semaphore(1, true);
    public static String content = "planets";
    public static int numOfReaders;

    static class Reader extends Thread {
        void read() {
            try {
                readMutex.acquire();
                numOfReaders++;
                if (numOfReaders == 1) {
                    accessToResource.acquire();
                }
                readMutex.release();

                // read content, not a critical section
                System.out.println("Read content:\t" + content);

                readMutex.acquire();
                numOfReaders--;
                if (numOfReaders <= 0) {
                    accessToResource.release();
                }
                readMutex.release();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            read();
        }
    }

static class Writer extends Thread {
    String text;

    Writer(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    void write() {
        try {
            readMutex.acquire();
            accessToResource.acquire();

            // critical section
            content = text;
            System.out.println("Content changed:\t" + content);
            // end of critical section

            accessToResource.release();
            readMutex.release();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        write();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Reader t1 = new Reader();
    Reader t2 = new Reader();
    Writer t3 = new Writer("stars");
    Reader t4 = new Reader();
    Writer t5 = new Writer("restaurant at the end of universe");
    Reader t6 = new Reader();
    Reader t7 = new Reader();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    t5.start();
    t6.start();
    t7.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one `Reader` has acquired `accessToResource` and try to acquire `readMutex`:

```
if (numOfReaders == 1) {
    accessToResource.acquire();
}
readMutex.release();

System.out.println("Read content:\t" + content);

readMutex.acquire();  // -------> here
```

while another `Writter` has acquired `readMutex` and try to acquire `accessToResource`:

```
readMutex.acquire();
accessToResource.acquire(); // ------> here
```

dead lock happens.

Since the `accessToResource` and `readMutex`'s permit is `1`, neither the `Reader` nor the `Writter` could move forward.